# Gallery using FANCYBOX

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, jquery, html

I need to create FANCYBOX gallery like here: [example link](https://www.bestelectricradiators.co.uk/slimline-digital-electric-radiator)

Please give me documentation link where described such example and link for downloading according version.

Comment: Please approve answer if it is useful. So, other people can use this code. @John

Answer (score 1):

First you need to load jQuery and fancybox to your page:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

After add link to the image which you want to display in fancybox :

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/large-image-name.jpg" class="various"><img src="http://www.yoursite.com/small-image-name.jpg" /><a>
```

now you need to run fancybox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth      : 450,
        maxHeight     : 350,
        fitToView     : false,
        width         : '70%',
        height        : '70%',
        autoSize      : false,
        showNavArrows : true,
        openEffect    : 'none',
        closeEffect   : 'none'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension for fancy box gallery

This may help

> https://templates-master.com/magento-easy-lightbox.html